# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Отборы «+» и «-» от камеры при измерении расходов жидкостей устанавливают сбоку (,)перпендикулярно оси трубопровода для исключения погрешности измерений от воздушных «подушек».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливаются где? - сбоку. Устанавливаются как? - перпендикулярно оси. Эти обстоятельства неоднородны, так как отвечают на разные вопросы, поэтому запятая не нужна. Но можно рассматривать  словосочетание "перпендикулярно оси трубопровода" как уточняющее обстоятельство, поэтому возможна, но нежелательна запятая как авторский знак